# Visual Basic 2010 Express Form to Database

Tags: database, vb.net, events

I made an input form that I want to work like a daily diary.  The user inputs a title, date, time, and the actual text entry.  At the end is a button and I think I have to make a click "event" to make all the text from the input boxes get stored somewhere.  I want each of these submissions to be separate for each day with the capability of showing the journal entry for each day later on.

I am a novice, but I think the data needs to go to a database.  Cannot find any sample code to make the form data save to a database.  The database I made is "a local database."  Not sure if it needs to be "Dataset" or "Entity Data Model".

Please show me some code for this or a way to save information without a database only using vb code.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of different ways to do this. Even with VB Net you still need to write some code to save the things from a form you would like to save.
The question your asking has no simple answer. From your question I think that you do not really have as they say a “common frame of reference” to understand the answers someone might post for you here.
You will need to know what database you are using and have an ideal of the proper ways to connect to that database. And you will need to look at ways to process your data to and from your database. With whatever method you will need to know some basic SQL, you know “Select this from that where something = those” along with sql insert and update etc.

Left me give you a very “terse” example of how to get data from a form to a database, so that you can understand a little of the scope of the challenge.

Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

Dim newid As Integer=Insert(Textbox1.text)

End Sub

Function Insert(ByVal Ruling As String) As Integer

```
        Dim Con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(vConString)

        Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = Con.CreateCommand

        Dim c As Integer = 0

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Ruling

        cmd.CommandText = "InsertRuling"


        Try
            Dim R As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
            Con.Open()
            R = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While R.Read()
                c = R.Item(0)
            End While
            R.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debugger.Break() '  
        Finally
            If Not Con Is Nothing Then
                Con.Close()
            End If
        End Try
        Return c
    End Function
```

This function connects to the database, inserts a record and returns the new ID (Primary Key) of the new record.
The Stored procedure is a stored procedure in the database (in this case the database is SQL server, most databases have stored procedures). The parameter contains the actual value I am writing to the database. 
Here is the stored procedure, BTW the stored procedure is something you write, it is not something that already exists in the database.

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InsertRuling

```
@title as nvarchar(50
```

AS

INSERT INTO Rulings
                         (Title)
VALUES        (@title)

/* SET NOCOUNT ON */

```
SELECT @@identity as nid
```

/* SET NOCOUNT ON */

```
RETURN
```

You could also forgo the procedure, and just write to the database directly by changing a few things in your function.

```
    Sub Insert(ByVal Ruling As String)

        Dim Con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(vConString)

        Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = Con.CreateCommand


        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Rulings (Title) VALUES (" & Ruling & ")" 


        Try
            Con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debugger.Break() '  
        Finally
            If Not Con Is Nothing Then
                Con.Close()
            End If
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Any method you use requires you to be able to write SQL. Net provides a way to wire your controls directly to the database using datasets, however you still need to be able to understand how to write sql, and understand something about the data you will be reading and writing from the database. The update, insert and select statements to the database are auto generated but you still need to have some kind of common frame of reference with SQL to understand when and how to use them, and also modify them. 
Go to a book store and get a big book on programming VB.net. There are several out there and they all cover the basics of VB net and databases and will give you enough SQL syntax to muddle through about anything, then as you gain experience it will get easier.